# Google Cloud Storage returning wrong identity

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

On my local machine I've been working on two differents projects with different accounts, etc, none of this projects are related, so.

Let's imagine that the two projects have the following emails:

first-project@gmail.com
second-project@gmail.com

For the second project (second-project@gmail.com) I made an API using nodejs where I have a endpoint to upload files, so I am trying to upload a file to a butcket using postman, the configuration on my nodejs endpoint have the project id of the second-project@gmail.com account and also have the bucket name that exist on second-project@gmail.com, here is the code of my upload file:

```
const GCStorage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const Multer = require('multer');

const CLOUD_BUCKET = 'mybucketname';

const storage = new GCStorage.Storage({
  projectId: '1234657890'
});
const bucket = storage.bucket(CLOUD_BUCKET);

// Returns the public, anonymously accessable URL to a given Cloud Storage
// object.
// The object's ACL has to be set to public read.
// [START public_url]
function getPublicUrl(filename) {
  return `https://storage.googleapis.com/${CLOUD_BUCKET}/${filename}`;
}
// [END public_url]

// Express middleware that will automatically pass uploads to Cloud Storage.
// req.file is processed and will have two new properties:
// * ``cloudStorageObject`` the object name in cloud storage.
// * ``cloudStoragePublicUrl`` the public url to the object.
// [START process]
function sendUploadToGCS(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.file) {
    return next();
  }

  const gcsname = Date.now() + req.file.originalname;
  const file = bucket.file(gcsname);

  const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype
    },
    resumable: false
  });

  stream.on('error', err => {
    req.file.cloudStorageError = err;
    next(err);
  });

  stream.on('finish', () => {
    req.file.cloudStorageObject = gcsname;
    file.makePublic().then(() => {
      req.file.cloudStoragePublicUrl = getPublicUrl(gcsname);
      next();
    });
  });

  stream.end(req.file.buffer);
}
// [END process]

// Multer handles parsing multipart/form-data requests.
// This instance is configured to store images in memory.
// This makes it straightforward to upload to Cloud Storage.
// [START multer]
const multer = Multer({
  storage: Multer.MemoryStorage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 // no larger than 5mb
  }
});
// [END multer]

module.exports = {
  getPublicUrl,
  sendUploadToGCS,
  multer
};
```

but I getting the following error:

```
{
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'forbidden',
      message: 'first-project@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.create access to mybucketname/1578598638283DeveloperInPixelsLogo1.png.'
    }
```

As you can see the message contains the email address of the first-project@gmail.com But this are diferents projects and account so I can't understand what is happening here, any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `storage` object you're creating is [using Application Default Credentials (ADCs)](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/4969148f5e114d86aa4928109f099ec15d56fda5/src/storage.ts#L362); it's probably loading credentials for a service account from your first project.

If you want to use always credentials for the second project's service account, you should either [ensure your environment is configured correctly](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production), or use the `Storage` [constructor that allows passing in explicit credentials](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/4969148f5e114d86aa4928109f099ec15d56fda5/src/storage.ts#L369), rather than trying to load them from the default sources.